# Xamarin Android Right Navigation Drawer - only right

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, navigation-drawer

[This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itfCvwZqR9g) focuses on how to implement a right navigation drawer in conjunction with a left navigation drawer using the action bar drawer toggle from support library v7.

I want only  Right Navigation Drawer 
how to?

Menu icon to right? not left

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can  set a single  ListView like this:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- The Left navigation drawer -->
        <!--<ListView -->
            <!--android:id="@+id/left_drawer"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="240dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_gravity="start"-->
            <!--android:choiceMode="singleChoice"-->
            <!--android:divider="@android:color/transparent"-->
            <!--android:dividerHeight="0dp"-->
            <!--android:background="#111"/>-->

        <!-- The Right navigation drawer -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#E2E2E2"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="#9E9E9E"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The property: `android:layout_gravity="right"` means that load it form  right, set it as a  `Left Navigation Drawer`. You can adjust the menu icon’s position by `Toolbar`.

If you want more details information, you can see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqRXHRs3_4I&feature=youtu.be).